Who paid for communal services and how was that managed?
In the times of Chazal (post churban) how were communal good and services handled? Meaning things like the cost of creating a road, establishing and maintaining a jail or any other need a community had. I assume those things were paid for by a tax but would like to understand more about that.

Was the tax administered by the town?
Was it tiered based on income level?
Was it halachically enforceable?
Were there guidelines on the use of community funds, for example if Yanky could build a jail for 100 shekels and Dovid offered to do it for 95 shekels did you have to go with Dovid?


What evidence do you have that suggests that we built roads or maintained jails?

@Deuteronomy the mishna discusses maintaining roads and discusses court cases which require incarceration before sentencing. besides which I don't know that we would need evidence for what was standard practice for running a society in those days, I would argue we would need evidence against it

"mishna discusses maintaining roads and discusses court cases which require incarceration before sentencing" Please cite the relevant Mishanyoth. The Mishnah refers to many things that are not done post-hurban. Are you sure they do not refer to when we have sovereignty and are dwelling in our land (i.e. pre-hurban)? "I don't know that we would need evidence for what was standard practice for running a society in those days" throughout exile we haven't exactly been "running society"

IIRC, Jewish communities around the world were not independent in the last 2,100 years. It appears that your question deals with the municipal and state levels, both of which were managed by the local rule - Greeks, Romans, Persians, etc. All Jews paid taxes, but they also managed local Tzeddakka funds that were used for the religious needs of the community, as well as financial support to its members.

If you notice, the highest level of Jewish Halachic control (as per Rambam) is the Laws of Neighbors.  The lack of higher-level guidance points to the submission to local regulations as reflected in the Dina DeMalchuta Dina principle.

It seems that in Jewish society people were not kept in jail for extended amount of time. Instead they were sold as slaves to live with an honorable family, and contribute to its livelihood by performing labor in a caring environment upto 6 years.

@YDJ I believe there was imprisonment for capital cases which would require things like a jail, food, an outhouse, possibly security. All of which would have to be paid for

@rikitikitembo for how long would the court decide on a capital case? How often?

@YDJ not sure it would matter. if a town apprehends no criminals for a month or a year do they close down the jail?

@rikitikitembo they did not have enough capital criminals to convict one once in 70 years. They had reasonably quick trials and sent unintentional killers to cities of refuge others were sold as slaves.

with exceedingly rare exception, capital punishment was not practiced in exile... whereas your question concerns the post-hurban context.
